# pandas DataFrame round

Tags: python, pandas, rounding

Disclaimer: I am a Python novice

I would like to ask if anyone might know why pandas DataFrames can accept np.round() if the DataFrame is copied from, for example, df.describe(), but it does not work if I create the DataFrame manually using a separately defined key/label strings:

```
df = {}
index = [...index list...]
columns = [...key list...]
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
```

gives "AttributeError: rint" if I insert values and then apply np.round(). If I copy df.describe(), change some values and then do np.round() it works fine. Both are DataFrames so I don't see why the behaviour could be different.

code example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo1' : np.random.randn(5),'foo2' : np.random.randn(5)})
df1.iloc[:,0] = np.round(df1.iloc[:,0],decimals=3) # works fine
df1

df2 = {}
index = ['foo1','foo2','foo3']
columns = ['oof1','oof2']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

num = 0
for i in df1.median():
   df2.ix[0,num] = df1.median()[num]
   df2.ix[1,num] = df1.median()[num]
   df2.ix[2,num] = df1.median()[num]
   num += 1

np.around(df2.ix[:,0],decimals=3) # gives 'AttributeError: rint'
```

Comment: Can you expand this to a reproducible example so we can see what the problem is?  Use dummy data if you need to.

Comment: Ok. I will work on it.

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo1' : np.random.randn(5),'foo2' : np.random.randn(5)})
df1.iloc[:,0] = np.round(df1.iloc[:,0],decimals=3) # works fine
df1

df2 = {}
index = ['foo1','foo2','foo3']
columns = ['oof1','oof2']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)

num = 0
for i in df1.median():
    df2.ix[0,num] = df1.median()[num]
    df2.ix[1,num] = df1.median()[num]
    df2.ix[2,num] = df1.median()[num]
    num += 1

np.around(df2.ix[:,0],decimals=3) # gives 'AttributeError: rint'

Comment: Just edit into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for providing an example.

The problem is that the dtypes in your second dataframe are 'object.'  You can convert those to floats with the following code:

```
In [47]: df2 = df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

In [48]: np.around(df2.ix[:,0],decimals=3)
Out[48]: 
foo1   -0.039
foo2   -0.039
foo3   -0.039
Name: oof1, dtype: float64
```

In general, it's often better to build an entire DataFrame at once, rather than building it cell-by-cell like in your df2.  For example, you could do something like this and avoid having to convert dtypes.

```
In [50]: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'oof1': df1['foo1'].median(),
    ...:                     'oof2': df1['foo2'].median()}, index=index)

In [51]: np.around(df2.ix[:,0],decimals=3)
Out[51]: 
foo1   -0.039
foo2   -0.039
foo3   -0.039
Name: oof1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand why DataFrames might behave differently. My actual code is a little bit more complicated in the sense that each column has different precision and it seems the code is shorter if I change the dtype afterwards.